# Python - Create a new file after the original file exceeds N lines

Tags: python

I have a directory with 50 files. Each file has around 100K lines. I am parsing the files and extracting the lines that fit certain criteria. The new file is much smaller than the first file, probably around 30K lines. I would like to read from input files and write into output file until output file reaches 100K lines. After that, I would create a new output file and continue writing into it. Something like this

```
import os
path='/path/to/directory'
listing=os.listdir(path)
with open('outfile','w') as f2:
    for filename in listing:
        for line in filename:
            if condition met:
                f2.write(line)
```

reads all files from directory and writes everything into outfile. Now, how do I set the criteria to create a new outfile, let's say outfile1 when outfile reaches 100K lines?

Comment: Add a counter and a condition on it?

Comment: Have you considered using `logging` instead of writing to the file by hand?

Comment: How to add a condition? I am not really experienced with python (as you can see). I need to continue reading from the list of input files and keep creating new output files. Kevin, I saw logging as an option but I have no experience with it

Comment: By doing `for line in filename:` you're not reading the **content** of the files in listing, only iterating through the characters of their name.

Comment: yes, i need to go through characters in my case since I need to read every x characters, see if they match a certain pattern, then through next y characters and so on

Comment: Characters of the **name** of the file or characters contained **in** the file? From your question it seems like you want to do the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some pseudocode, I figured its easier to get rid of the file contexts (it saves opening and closing the same file several times):

```
count, sk, lines = 100000, 0, 0
f2 = open('outfile0', 'w')
for filename in listing:                
    for line in filename:
       if condition met:               
           if lines > count:                   
               f2.close()
               sk, lines = sk+1, 0
               f2 = open('outfile%s'%sk, 'w')
           f2.write(line) 
           lines += 1
 f2.close()
```

Comment: you'll need to check for boundary conditions too. I'll update the answer to include this later...gtr

Answer (score 1):

The dir to open is passed as the first command line argument. I made up an artificial condition using random.randint() to test the script and set a limit per outfile of 10 lines:

```
import sys
import os
import random

assert os.path.isdir(sys.argv[1])
listing = os.listdir(sys.argv[1])

l_index, f_name, f_index, f_max = 0 , 1, 0, 10

f2 = open('outfile0','w')

for filename in listing:

    with open(sys.argv[1]+"/"+listing[l_index],'r') as f1:

        for line in f1:

            if ( f_index > f_max ):
                f2.close()
                f2 = open('outfile'+str(f_name),'w')
                f_index, f_name = 0, f_name + 1

            if random.randint(0,100)%100 > 50:
                f2.write(line)
                f_index += 1
```